# Assigning value using setProperty

Tags: jsp, usebean

I have made a JSP page which has `<jsp:useBean>`. The problem is that, whenever the form is submitted, the value of `testName` is `null` in bean and same for `timLim`.

```
<form method="POST" action="test-panel.jsp">
                        <table>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
<input style="width:300px" name="testName" type="text" required pattern="[0-9 A-Za-z\\s]*" maxlength="100">
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
<input style="width:100px" name="timLim" type="text" pattern="[0-9\\s]*" required maxlength="3">
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <div style="width:100px">
                            <select name="queRand">
                                                <option value="1">Yes
                                                </option>
                                                <option value="0">No
                                                </option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Next">
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                      </form>
    <jsp:useBean class="pack1.TD1" id="td2" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>
    <jsp:setProperty name="td2" property="testName" param="testName"></jsp:setProperty>
    <jsp:setProperty name="td2" property="timLim" param="timLim"></jsp:setProperty>
    <jsp:setProperty name="td2" property="queRand" param="queRand"></jsp:setProperty>
    <%
        td2.saveTestDetails(false);
    %>
```

Comment: You should use MVC to split business logic and view. It's not easy to read this code.

Comment: @Alex tell me what are you unable to understand?

Comment: What is the current page? What is test-panel.jsp file? If you use MVC you will get clean code.

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste your bean class too?